# python code on Heroku errors where it works locally

Tags: python, pandas, heroku

I am getting too many errors on Heroku, so any print statements are not showing up in logs. This code works fine locally (python on windows 10) but wont work on Heroku, where it tells me there is nothing to concat...

```
path = r'.\store\tx' # use path for csv files
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path , "tastyworks_tx*.csv")) # 

li = []
print(all_files)    

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    print('filename: ', filename)
    input('pause here..')
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)   #append all the files to a single dataframe called "frame"
```

I have checked the `\store\tx` folder on Heroku and the `tastyworks_tx*.csv` files are present and I have other functions that can access files inside of the store folder but they use forward slanting (e.g. `hist_data = pd.read_csv('./store/hist5m.csv', index_col=0, header=[0, 1])` works fine ).

On Heroku I get the following error.

> 2022-08-18T05:35:28.470644+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/./main.py",
> line 291, in tastytx 2022-08-18T05:35:28.470644+00:00 app[web.1]:
> frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)   #append all the
> files to a single dataframe called "frame"

...

> raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
> 2022-08-18T05:35:28.470645+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: No objects to
> concatenate

my python dependencies used are same version as on the local setup, though the local setup has more installed. Here is my "requirements.txt" file for Heroku that installs fine:

> pandas==1.4.2, pandas-datareader==0.10.0, DateTime==4.4, yfinance==0.1.72, fastapi==0.79.0, uvicorn==0.18.2, beautifulsoup4==4.11.1

I dont want to give Heroku my credit card info so cannot install Papertrail or better logging addons and cant figure out how to find out more of what is going wrong here due to limits on the logs.

Comment: "I have other functions that can access files inside of the store folder but they use forward slanting" -> Have you tried changing this code to use forward slashes? Backslashes are not valid directory separators on linux.

Comment: @FiddleStix the ```all_files``` variable ends up looking like this with the working code ```['.\\store\\tx\\tastyworks_tx_2020.csv', '.\\store\\tx\\tastyworks_tx_2021.csv', '.\\store\\tx\\tastyworks_tx_2022.csv']``` in windows, but I am so far unable to achieve the equivalent that works between platforms. I tried using pathlib Path but also not figured it yet. I think you might be right about this being the crux of the issue though. ```os.path.join``` is supposed to select the correct slashes for the OS but cant test in heroku without logs.

Comment: @Fiddlestix. you were right, if you want to add it as an answer I will close it. Basically, I got rid of ```path = r'.\store\tx'``` and changed the next line to ```all_files = glob.glob('./store/tx/tastyworks_tx*.csv', recursive = True)``` and it now works in Windows locally and in Heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because you are using `\` instead of `/` in the path.

On Linux, which is probably the OS for your Heroku machine, directories are separated with '/'. Your code will be looking for a file called precisely `.\\store\\tx\\tastyworks_tx_2020.csv` rather than a file called `tastyworks_tx_2020.csv` in `.store/tx/`.

Another (IMO more rubust) solution to replacing `\` with `/` would be to use pathlib, which should work on all operating systems.

```py
from pathlib import Path

the_path = Path("store") / Path("tx")
all_files = the_path.glob("tastyworks_tx*.csv") 
...
```

Comment: when I checked what the new method creates in windows it shows me this 
 ```['./store/tx\\tastyworks_tx_2020.csv', './store/tx\\tastyworks_tx_2021.csv', './store/tx\\tastyworks_tx_2022.csv']``` which has back slashes, but works both on windows python and on Heroku. When it was not working on Heroku I was getting ```['.\\store\\tx\\tastyworks_tx_2020.csv', '.\\store\\tx\\tastyworks_tx_2021.csv', '.\\store\\tx\\tastyworks_tx_2022.csv']``` with my original code.

all attempts that failed related to ```./store``` aspect being unable to pass the ```./``` so it might be the issue was that too.